# Показать описание объекта на Яндекс.Картах

Tags: javascript, html, яндекс-карты

Есть маркер на яндекс карте, нужно настроить так, чтобы при щелчке на него появлялось описание, как я понял это балун называется. Но я абсолютный профан в яндекс картах, поэтому и прошу помощи  :)

[image: 123]

```
<script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    ymaps.ready(init);

    function init(){     

        var myMap;

        myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
            center: [51.52, 46.03],
            zoom: 7,
            controls: []
        });

        myMap.behaviors.disable('scrollZoom');

        myMap.controls.add("zoomControl", {
            position: {top: 15, left: 15}
        });
          var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([51.529731, 46.034944] , {},
        { iconLayout: 'default#image',
          iconImageHref: 'img/yandex-marker.png',
          iconImageSize: [45, 52],
          iconImageOffset: [-20, -47] }); 
            myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);


    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [конструктор карт Яндекс](https://yandex.ru/map-constructor/?from=maps_login).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код css для скрытия "лишней" информации с карты:

```
/* Yandex Map */
ymaps.ymaps-2-1-45-button__text {
    display: none;
}
ymaps.ymaps-2-1-45-scaleline {
    display: none;
}
ymaps.ymaps-2-1-45-map-copyrights-promo {
    display: none;
}
ymaps.ymaps-2-1-45-copyright.ymaps-2-1-45-copyright_logo_no {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Карта через конструктор не подойдет,  мне нужна карта через Api (нужно оставить на карте только масштабирование), а через обычный конструктор как я понял это реализовать невозможно.

Comment: Понимаю, что не совсем то, что нужно, но вот здесь http://polati.zephyrlab.ru/ в самом низу, делал через конструктор и убирал лишнее с помощью css.

Comment: даже не подумал о css, а каким образом убирать лишнее, через display: none ?

Comment: да, сейчас выдерну код с этого сайта и добавлю код в ответ

Comment: Добавил код css

Comment: Благодарю, буду пробовать